# Android ROOM - How to Insert a Object inside an Object (i.e. Flash Card Deck has a List of Questions)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room, android-database

As per the title,
I have been confused on how I would implement the following:
A FlashCard deck has a title, due date (both have been implemented).
However, it also contains a List of Cards.
A Card is made up of a question and answer.

Like this, Deck(title, duedate, flashcards). Cards(question, answer)

I have been thinking about using a dedicated typeconverter for this. However,
it can also get messy.

For example,
I was thinking of having a type converter which collects all the existing questions and answers into a concatonated csv string. Then it will deconvert this when transitioning back into the object.

This method seems quite complicated. Therefore, I was wondering what is the best practice per se, for this sort of thing.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do think your problem is a database schema problem. So basically there are 2 solutions depending on how you want to use the cards.

**1. If the card does not repeat in any deck or if each and every card is unique:**

Then you can use this schema:-[image]

For finding all cards for a particular deck say suppose "Deck 1" whose id is 1. You can use the SQL query `"SELECT * FROM Cards WHERE Deck_id=1;"`

*Pros:*

- You will have to maintain only two tables.
- Probably easy to write SQL Queries.

*Cons*

- You cannot reuse any cards. All cards will be unique.
- May require more storage space.

**2. If the card repeats, or if you want to reuse a card:**

Then you can use this schema:-[image]

For finding all cards for a particular deck say suppose "Deck 1" whose id is 1. You can use the SQL query `"SELECT * FROM Cards WHERE id IN(SELECT Cards_id FROM Deck_has_Cards WHERE Deck_id=1);"`

*Pros:*

- Saves a lots of storage space(if cards are not unique).

*Cons*

- Queries become very hard to write

I will recommend you to check for better SQL queries than those I have written.

If you are using Room Database use `@Query(<SQL>)...`(I am not expanding on this many tutorials are available).

I will not recommend the way you are trying to store the cards as it will be not working with the A.C.I.D. properties of the database.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the reply. This definitely helped me remember SQL days. Took a class in Uni for it but haven't thought much of it since.

Comment: Mention not, If i am able to solve your query can you please accept it as the answer.